# How to convert Chinese punctuation into English for the list elements?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to check the Unicode but, doesn't work properly.
Then I tried to remove punctuation so, I can merge them at the end.

```
def remove_punctuations(text):
    for punctuation in string.punctuation:
    text = str(text).replace(punctuation, '')
    return textlst_1  =lst_1.apply(remove_punctuations)  

lst_1= lst1.str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '')
lst_1 = ['SRS ????','NAT ????', 'Ins ??','SRS 檢視試針',
   'NAT 酒精清洗', 'Ins 目測']
```

Comment: What is the problem/error you are getting, please provide it from `trackback` to end in question. And is your question related to `machine-learning` and `data-science` because you haven't mentioned anything about it in your question. Please either try to remove it or mentioned about that in your question. For further information you can visit [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly